# Should I always use a 1D vector with my own indexing, or is a multi-dimensional vector ok?

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm storing and generating some data that is naturally represented with dimension > 1. However, I have seen many answers recommend that programmers use a 1D vector with their own custom index to represent the multiple dimensions. My question is: What is to be gained by only using 1-Dimension?

On my current project, performance is a priority (I know code first, then profile, but this project is being imported into C++ from another language for speed). I could see how only having a single vector object could reduce overhead, but is it that much more than frequently calculating indices? I saw one answer mentioned that using nested vectors:

```
vector < vector<int> >
```

Causes a lot of calls to `new`. I could see how this is troubling, is this true?

Comment: There is a semantic difference: The nested `vector`s allow so-called jagged arrays, where `arr[i].size() != a[j].size()` for some `i =! j`.

Comment: This could be done with a 1-D vector, and a more complicated indexing scheme, right?

Comment: Not with the same 1D vector, you need additional metadata (you *may* be able to come up with a hack to also store that in the same 1D array, but that's just an awful implementation of "additional metadata").

Comment: Don't you always need additional metadata, like the size of your second dimension? Or is there some way to get around that which I don't know about?

Comment: Yeah, you have such metadata, or extra indirection, with nested arrays too -- the difference is that you don't need to care about it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` can have inner vectors of varying sizes. However, I'll assume that you're talking specifically about using this type to mimic 2D arrays. Assuming you set up the sizes of the vectors when you create them, you probably don't need to worry about the amount of dynamic allocation, since it all happens in one go.

A vector internally allocates an array of its elements. So the outer vector is allocating an array of vectors and each of those inner vectors is allocating an array of `int`s. You can think of it like this:

```
┌─────┐
│ vec │
└──╂──┘
   ┃
   ▼
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ vec │ vec │ vec │ vec │ vec │ vec │ vec │ vec │ vec │
└──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┴──╂──┘
   ┃     ┗━━━━━━━━━━┓
   ▼                ▼
┌─────┬─────┬┄   ┌─────┬─────┬┄
│ int │ int │    │ int │ int │
└─────┴─────┴┄   └─────┴─────┴┄
```

As you can see, the arrays of `int`s are entirely separate from each other. They might be in completely different locations of memory. This is known as fragmentation. They almost certainly won't be in a single contiguous block of memory. Because of this, accessing elements across different "rows" of your 2D vector will likely result in cache misses.

However, if you allocate a single vector of `int`s and do your own 2-dimensional indexing, you have a memory layout more like this:

```
┌─────┐
│ vec │
└──╂──┘
   ┃
   ▼
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬┄
│ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴┄
```

The `int`s are now stored in a single contiguous block of memory. Any accesses are likely to have similar memory addresses and result in a cache hit. This could potentially give you a performance gain.

Comment: You should also look into [std::valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/). It provides improved performance for some operations and also provides fast access to subparts through the use of [std::slice](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/slice/) and [std::gslice](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/gslice/)